# validation of links of a markdown on node.js by async await

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building a node.js proyect that allows you to read the broken or invalid links of a markdown. Right now i've created 3 modules that give you the directory, shows you the content of the files that end with .md and the third one has a function that looks for all the urls. I'm building another module that will validate the urls, but im having trouble with my promises, this is my code.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const linksrs = require('./linksrs');
const comandL = require('./cli');

const colors = require('colors');
colors.setTheme({
  stats: 'blue',
  file: 'cyan',
  text: 'green',
  error: 'red',

});
 const markdownSearchLinks = (data) => {
  console.log(markdownPath)
  const regex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;

  const result = data.match(regex);
  console.log(result);

};

const links = async () => {
    read(markdownSearchLinks()) 
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
}
```

Comment: what trouble are you having? the lack of any `return` statements, and not passing any arguments to a function that requires them, suggests your issue is with how javascript works in general, not just Promises

Comment: `markdownSearchLinks = (data) => ` ... but you call it like `markdownSearchLinks()` ... you `console.log(markdownPath)`, but `markdownPath` isnt' declared anywhere. You call `read(.....)` but `read` is not defined anywhere either ... none of these basic problems have anything to do with Promises

Comment: the `markdownSearchLinks` function has to match the urls of the .md files with the regex and then i want to show the status of each of the urls.

Comment: Right, so, what is the data argument meant to be? what should this function return? None of that is at all obvious from the code you posted

Comment: what argument does `read` require? does `links` function need to return something?

Comment: `markdownSearchLinks` should return all the links from the .md files, wow I'm just checking my code again and it makes no sense... (btw, im 3 months in js im a total newbie).